# Super slow OpenGL graphics on AMD 760G/SB710 chipset motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, graphics, integrated-graphics, opengl

I have a [Biostar A780L3L motherboard](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/driver.php?S_ID=495) with an AMD 760G/SB710 chipset. Drawing even very few and very simple 2D objects using OpenGL runs ridiculously slow (1 fps). I assume there are no hardware OpenGL drivers, but the performance doesn't even make sense for software OpenGL emulation.

This is on Windows 8 x64. I installed the windows 8 x64 drivers for G series embedded Radeon graphics. I *think* performance improved slightly, but now I'm still getting about 2 frames per second with a single 48x48 pixel graphic moving up and down.

Are there other drivers I need? Do I need to do something special with OpenGL? My software-OpenGL computer from 18 years ago was much faster than this.

Everything else with the computer seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a pain to get this to work. So I found out how to install the chipset drivers. I can search for AMD 7xxx series chipsets and select windows 7 x64. It actually brings me to the windows 8 x64 screen, which is what I want (it's the only way to get to this screen). I install those. Doesn't help. I need the drivers, but the newest graphics drivers don't work. I find this link that just came available 5 days ago apparently. [Legacy drivers to allow my graphics chipset to work in Windows 8](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalystlegacywin8.aspx).

Unfortunately, installing that doesn't work either. But it does give me the Catalyst Control Center (just no graphics options). So then I manually update my driver within Windows 8 pointing to the directory that was created from that install. **Finally** it works and OpenGL performance is usable!

Answer (score 0):

installing legacy AMD CIM added folders for display drivers and installed OpenGL as needed for Minecraft to be able to use onboard graphics.